# Microsoft Smart Art in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I can't seem to position Smart Art in Word (for Mac) 2016.

When I insert it, it is inserted at the full width of the page (minus margins).  However the 'box' is empty (doesn't show graphics) and is not at the insertion point I indicated.

If I move it, it just snaps back to where it originally positioned

Comment: It may have been a bad wrap setting, but I chose to out the smart art on a different page, enlarge it, screen shot it, the use the image and delete the smart art.  I KNOW how to position images